# Flutter as a UIModule

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm studying flutter as a module: UIModule (Only components and abstract/interface behaviors).

The idea is apply inheritance between native and flutter to define a context implementation in native layer. Or use a uicomponent written on flutter module to use in native project.

This is strategy is possible?